# Sufficient conditions for an entire functions to be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Which of the following are correct?

1. $f$ is constant if range of $f$ is contained in a straight line
2. $f$ is constant if it has uncountable number of zeros
3. $f$ is constant if $f$ is bounded on $\{z:\operatorname{Re}(z)\leq 0\}$
4. $f$ is constant if $\operatorname{Re}(f)$ is bounded

---

2. is correct by analytic continuation

4. is correct on considering $e^f$.

Are they only ones?

Comment: Apparently so (did you try to come up with a counterexample for 3? It's a well known function). I'm not quite clear on the meaning of 1. The imaginary part is of course real, so contained in the real line...

Comment: I have edited it @Idisagree

Comment: Well, then the open mapping theorem should do it for 1.

Comment: that means you say 1 is correct@Idisagree

Comment: Yes, this is the conclusion you should get from the theorem.

Comment: all right I will try

Comment: if the range of f is contained in a straight line then choosing a proper linear map g(z)=az+b we have g(f) is real. But then, by using Cauchy -Riemann equation, we have g(f) and hence f as a constant.

Comment: If range of f is contained in a straight line then by a suitable g(z)=az+b we have g(f) having range is real. Using Cauchy-Riemann equations we see that g(f) is constant and hence f is constant

Answer (score 1):

To summarize:

1. True by the open mapping theorem. A more direct approach from Cauchy Riemann equations is also possible, see the comments by Adelafif.
2. True by the identity principle, since an uncountable set must have a point of accumulation.
3. The exponential function answers this one.
4. True by Liouville's theorem applied to $\exp(f)$.