# Is the following function a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is entire and bounded on the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}; Re(z) \leq 0\}$. Is $f$ a constant function.

I know by Picards theorem that a non-constant entire function assumes all but one value in the complex plane. Can this result be tweaked and applied here? Any hints?

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334523/sufficient-conditions-for-an-entire-functions-to-be-constant)'s the full question, asked much earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f(z) = e^z$. Then, for any $z$ such that $Re(z) \leq 0$, we have that $f(z)$ is contained in the (closed) unit circle, yet $f$ is not constant.

Comment: ..with radius $1$..

Comment: @Berci While, strictly speaking, I wasn't wrong, I'll give you that one.